# Can liberalism be proven logically

Tags: political-philosophy

Can modern, Democrat Liberal ideology be proven logically, ie, does it extend rationally from logical axioms, or does it have other means of axiomatization.

Comment: No ideology, or anything of substance, can be "proven from logical axioms", not even mathematical theorems. All logical axioms entail are [logical tautologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)). Please clarify the question.

Comment: Based on the user’s other answer on this stack, this appears to be little more than a loaded question/political insult rather than a genuine attempt to seek knowledge. I think this should be closed.

Comment: @HHuang The Op’s other questions are not relevant. This question is well-formed and respectful, even if half-baked. That’s all that matters. We respond to questions here, not a user’s post history. Moreover, if a user has asked some loaded or inappropriate questions at some time in some sites, it does not follow every question he asks is loaded on all sites. People don’t fall into two discrete categories - trolls vs. respectable.

Answer (score 1):

A political theory or philosophy is more or less equivalent to an *induction*. In other words, a theorist will begin with some insights about the nature of humans in society and will generalize from those insights to an abstract universal system.

Inductions aren't *proved* in the sense of deductive logic; inductions are *inferred*, and tested.

Specifically for Liberalism, the early Liberal philosophers had certain insights about human nature — a capacity for reason, a necessary investment in labor for continued survival, an intrinsic political equality, etc — and inferred various principled systems of governance, economics, and society that maximized those characteristics and minimized certain weaknesses. These principles were then implemented within various democratic republics. But the success of those republics is not guaranteed (as it would be if they were produced through mere deduction). Each form of republic is effectively an experimental model that is being tested through its real-time practice.

With luck, someone is paying attention to which experiments work and which don't, and learning How to improve the Liberal project. If not, well... please pick which Mad Max movie you'd like to live in.

Comment: What if america is the mad max movie

Answer (score -1):

It can't be "proven" in any sense, but liberalism is, in theory, an extension of certain "self-evident" axioms, equality chief among them. Obviously, equality is not an observable fact, quite the opposite, and so it may be deemed purely axiomatic.

The logical extension, however, is not necessarily liberalism. Hobbes begins with the assertion that all men are "equally" capable of killing each other and uses this to "prove" the necessity of absolute executive authority.

As an outgrowth of the Enlightenment, theories of liberalism, from Locke to Rawls, are generally developed through axioms and "rational" arguments, as opposed to dogma, faith, custom, or moral ideals.

But this is theory, not proof. The existence of many other forms of government is empirical proof that there is nothing logically necessary about any one type of government.